# Why isn't there a data type for just a date?

Tags: c#, .net

One of the first things I learned about dates and times in c# (and various other languages) is that a date is stored as a DateTime with the time component set to midnight.  There is no difference between "Jan 1, 2017" and "January 1, 2017 00:00:00.000".  If you need to display just a date, you can use formatting functions like `ToString` to remove the time portion.

This seems to cause a lot of problems, a few of which I shall list here:

1. DateTime takes up more storage space than needed: 8 bytes instead of the 3 required for a simple date.
2. Use of 00:00:00 for "no date" conflates "a known value of 0" with "unknown value." This seems rather noobish, in the same way a new programmer might confuse a null string with an empty string.  Null and empty are different, and "no time" and "midnight" are different ideas.
3. You see idioms like this one poppping up, even in relatively simple comparisions:

   ```
   if (startDate >= myDateTime && myDateTime < endDate.AddDays(1))
   ```

   or

   ```
   if (startDateTime >= myDate && myDate <= endDateTime.Date)
   ```

   instead of a far simpler

   ```
   if (startDate >= myDate && myDate <= endDate)
   ```
4. When system components located in different time zones call each other over web services, and the schema for those web services is generated from c# types, a time element can be introduced (so that the resulting date occurs early in the morning), or the date value actually may shift by a day (e.g. the final date is actually the prior day at a time late in the evening).  This can make it painful to transmit values that are agnostic with respect to timezone, e.g. a date of birth, or a credit card expiration date.

SQL Server has a `Date` type that stores only month, day, and year.

[XSD](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp) specifies different data types for Date, Time, and DateTime.

Why doesn't c# have such a type?

How do you work around it?  For example, can c# properties be attributed so that they will serialize as a Date instead of a DateTime?

Comment: Because the BCL isn't exactly well designed. You could use NodaTime if you care about clean modeling of dates and times.

Comment: You're always going to format a date in a display aren't you?

Comment: Of course.  That doesn't address bullet points 1, 2, 3, or 4 in my post, though; none of them require display to occur in order to present a problem.

Comment: Because C# isn't python, (which has a date type), so batteries aren't all included.

Comment: See answer from authoritative source here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058883/why-is-there-no-date-shorthand-of-system-datetime-in-c

Comment: Pretty much everything involving dates, times, and timezones is always going to suck and you might as well just make peace with that fact.

Comment: Thanks Dan, but Eric's answer addresses the question of "why isn't there an alias for DateTime like there is for other fundamental data types (e.g. `System.Int32` = `int`)?" It does not answer the question of why there is not a separate data type just for Date.

Comment: One way you could work around it is write your own date class.  You could even use Datetime as the underlying type, so that it is still backwards compatible.  Just set the time to midnight, and all of your date semantics will work correctly.

Comment: @Snowman: Transitivity is hardly present between these two questions; if anything, there is a [fallcious induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization) between your answers.

Comment: If you are worried about space you could do it as number of days since 1900 and get to 2079 with just 2 bytes.  And there is no datatype for 3 bytes.

Comment: @SnowMan: No, I am not asking about an alias.  I am asking about a separate type.  The relationship between a Date and a DateTime would be analogous to the relationship between an `int` and a `float`.  You are thinking about something akin to the relationship between an `int` and a `System.Int32`.

Comment: @JohnWu you are correct, I misread.

Comment: .NET is optimized to use 32-bit chunks of memory, so there wouldn't be a performance benefit for shaving off the bits for time.  Similarly, `bool` is not a single-bit, although it seems like it theoretically should be.

Comment: Also, if you want a better time library, use Noda Time http://nodatime.org/.  It doesn't really fix time in the way you want it, but looking at it you can see what is actually wrong with the default time in .NET.

Comment: A .NET DateTime is stored in 64 bits, so we're not exactly "shaving;"  we are halving, and then some.  But thank you for your comment.

Comment: The problems I have with the current implementation of Dates is that they're implemented as a point in time, while a date is actually a timespan.

Comment: To mangle a metaphor, this is the tip of the iceburg of a very deep rabbit hole. http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html

Answer (score 16):

What is a Date?

Let's say It's noon at your local region. You'll look at your clock and see something like 22/03/2017 12:00. You could say easily that this is the current date for everyone else in the world, right?

Well, not really. Chances are, if you are in London, or say, Russia, or the United States, your clock isn't really correct regarding those places. Your clock is marking the wrong time for the rest of the world, and for some places even the wrong date. When you talk about "the world", having a date without a time makes little to no sense once you start considering people outside your timezone. Just think how annoying it is to go to a foreigner website and seeing that, somehow, the user generated content there is coming from the future. That's what happens when you don't take into account timezones!

That's where C# DateTime goes in.

DateTime isn't the usual simple date you may need for local, just-my-company software. It is a somewhat powerful data structure that had the intent to be able to provide Universal Coordinated Time to any app. The magic part of the DateTime structure is that, with minor fiddling, you can make it display the correct DateTime for every single place in the world.

The idea behind DateTime was to provide not a simple Date object, but something you could use to represent dates all over the world, even with different Time Zones. It was made thinking in global applications, and thus it was designed with a bunch of extra functionalities that may not have apparent utility at first glance, but nevertheless can save a lot of time from people developing applications that will have to deal with variable time zones.

It is far from perfect, yes, but it does what it was meant for - representing Time in a universal, and somewhat portable, way.

So, in a sense, when using C# you are forced to consider times when developing your app, not only dates. And, really, that's a good thing - a DateTime is a reference point in time relative to *something*, and when you change your point of reference, the value for that DateTime must act accordingly.

To be totally fair, I think C# is one of the languages that got this thing right. You can have a Time interval without a date (TimeSpan is there for that), but you can't really have a meaningful date on a global scope without a reference frame and a time attached to it. I didn't like DateTime at all when I first met the language, but after having to develop an App with multiple timezones I understood why this design choice was actually a smart one.

Comment: Thank you for your post, which I completely understand, but disagree with as an historical account of what the DateTime type was "meant for" (your words).  The [Kind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind(v=vs.80).aspx) property wasn't even added until .NET 2.0. While I agree that a date cannot exist without a time, I believe that a date can exist without a *defined* time, e.g. when someone provides their date of birth they are hardly claiming to be born at midnight. We would typically represent this by providing a `null` time component.

Comment: @JohnWu Doesn't mean it wasn't on the blackboard. Several language features where only added later but where being considered for a long time already.  .NET 2.0 was _really early_ on the development cycle of the .NET Framework - the thing was merely a shadow of what was intended! Partial classes and Nullable types didn't exist before 2.0 too, and that doesn't make a "historical account" they weren't planned.

Comment: @JohnWu Also, DateTime had since 1.1 the [UtcNow Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.71).aspx), which already indicated the desire to make it timezone-compatible.

Comment: Thank you for your time TSar, I appreciate your perspective.  I think your answer went over some basic assumptions about DateTime that not all developers are familiar with.  But the purpose of my question is to *challenge* the assumption.

Comment: @JohnWu Dates are not expressed in discrete parts - you don't have a "Day" component, a "Month" component and a "Year" component. You have just a "Ticks" component which derives the rest. Dates are represented in memory using a long, so you can't have a null time - you don't have a separate time component.

Comment: @JohnWu I'm not using assumptions - the DateTime type was since the first spec supposed to be UTC compatible. You can't be UTC compatible without a time component because UTC dates don't exist without a time component. They are not discrete parts, they are a gigantic number that we, humans split as Dates and Times. _Time_ is an intrinsic part of any global representation of a date.

Comment: So, for example, in SQL Server, a date is a floating point number, where the integral portion is the date and the fraction is the time.  In c# we have both `float` and `int`, so it does not seem unreasonable to have both  `DateTime` (float) and `Date` (integer) data types.

Comment: So, how do you represent a birthday as a DateTime? There exists a clear use-case for Date only datatype.

Comment: So, is a person born in Canberra, Australia on 2017-03-28 younger than a person born in Phoenix, AZ, USA on 2017-03-27? It depends on the time, and the timezone, because even plain-old-dates can be complicated. The use-case space for date-only data types is actually very very small, perhaps too small to warrant their own data type, when you can already do everything you need to with the DateTime class.

Comment: @johnWu SQL server date type isn't UTC compatible

Comment: @Eric: It depends on the time and the timezone, *and* apparently it depends on where they were sitting when they entered the date of birth on a page.  That is the problem. If they enter 2017/03/28 from Bangalore, their DOB in UTC will be stored as 2017/03/27 18:30:00Z; if they entered it in London, the DOB will be 2017/03/28 00:00:00Z. Both are wrong if they were born in Arizona :)

Comment: @JohnWu Yep, and that problem can be addressed and rectified, or simply ignored, with a DateTime, but not with just a Date.

Comment: @Eric: Seems to me the best solution is to store what the user entered.  He entered a date.  He didn't intend to imply a time as well.  The only way to "fix" this with a `DateTime` is to accompany it with data about the user's browser's time zone; it is not possible with the `DateTime` alone. Or to pass the date as, say, an ISO-8601 date string, which makes me cringe.

Comment: @JohnWu Or just use a DateTime as a UCT time, displaying it back to the user as a date on his timezone - that you can grab when you are going to display it, via javascript or using a cookie - as _everybody else_ on the C# community does without issues since .NET 2.0. You don't need to store his timezone at all.

Comment: @Tsar: Then when he signs on again in London his date of birth will be off by a day. Nope.

Comment: @JohnWu You have to agree that bithdays are far less of a problem than, let's say, delivery dates or deadlines. People moving around the world and signing up on different timezones are far less significative than people ordering stuff from different timezones. While the example of the birthday is valid, it is also insignificant on the use-case seas that exists for UTC times.

Comment: @JohnWu In the end, it seems that you just came here to complain about something you didn't like about the language, not really to improve your knowledge about it or understand the reasons about it. This is not the place to whine about design choices made by Microsoft, Oracle, or any other company. I'm disengaging - this discussion went too far already. Feel free to downvote if you think my answer is bad.

Comment: As a side note, if using a DateTime built-in type isn't working for you to store a Birthday data structure, it's trivial (and perhaps better overall) to fight past [Primitive Obsession](https://www.google.com/search?q=primitive+obsession) and just build a Birthday class.

Comment: In all fairness, I do think there's a valid argument for John Wu from a business point of view. Sometimes we don't care about the exact time, but just want to have an official date regardless of your time zone. E.g. date on your Driver License. Even if you're in a -12 timezone, it should remain the same date. We're not interested in when the event actually occurred exactly, it's merely a historical milestone which should not 'change' based on your location. BUT, for any of these scenario's, do as @T.Sar suggests... use UTC time and display as a date, problem solved.

Comment: `Your clock is marking the wrong time for the rest of the world` While I do get your point and mostly agree with it; should you then not follow the same principle to conclude that _any_ DateTime must inherently carry timezone information with it? If the timezone information is optional, so should the time itself be.

Comment: Not correct. Date is independent of time zone. This was a huge mistake in .NET.

Comment: @CrouchingKitten When it is midnight on London, half of the world is on a different date.

Comment: @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica That's irrelevant. When data is persisted by date somewhere, you cannot convert it when observed from another time zone, it has to remain the same. Persisting data per date instead of timestamp always has this intention behind it. The reasons are related to the economic and other processes that deal with the data.

Comment: @CrouchingKitten You are mistaken. There are several processes that do need the stored timezone, specially when dealing with shipping, software releases, accounting and several other business types. A Date _has_ a timezone. It is an intrinsic property of it. You may choose not to use it, but that's your design choice. It is a simplification that you're opting to do.

Comment: @CrouchingKitten More specifically, a datetime is how many "ticks" you have since Timestamp Zero. A timezone is how you format that to get a human-readable date. [specific number of ticks] when converted to a certain timezone is 01/01/1990. The same [specific number of ticks] when converted to a different timezone might be 31/12/1989. And that's _alright_. Storing just a day-month-year tuple and ignoring timezone is your choice, but then again - you're not forced to use Datetime. Build your own object and use it, then.

Comment: @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica I can see that you never worked with time series data or in banking. Dates are never converted, because they stand for an aggregate bucket. Since the distribution of the source data is not known, it is not possible to re-establish the bucket boundaries. If the dates would carry the time zones in them, then they would not be comparable, then `Date1 > Date2` would have to return null if their time zones differ. This is never the case in practice, therefore the dates are universal and time zone-independent.

Comment: @CrouchingKitten You are mistaken. I do work right in the middle of data processing, and worked for almost five years in banking software. Date1 and Date2 are comparable between timezones because they are never stored as dates, but offsets of ticks. The "yyyy-mm-dd" format is just a human readable thing, not how they are stored down in the metal.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't such a class in the CLR standard libraries, but there is often a need for such a thing, for the reasons you have identified and others.

You can import the "Noda" library for C# and use [LocalDate](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.LocalDate.html) to represent a date without a specific time.

This class is based on a similar class from the Java library "Joda", which was found to be so useful and well written that it has now been imported into the Java standard libraries: [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

When converting from a `LocalDate` (without a time) to a standard `DateTime` (with a time component), the library forces you to make your assumptions explicit, so it avoids all kinds of edge cases and mistakes that you have identified in your question and in the discussion on T. Sar's answer

Comment: This is an constructive answer that provided useful alternative if you *need* to represent a "Date-only" information for some scenarios, even if it's clear from other answers that a Date only is completely ambiguous and is not a clear point or interval in time.

Answer (score 4):

Anthony Moore provides [a blog entry with some historical notes specifically on DateTime](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2007/06/18/a-brief-history-of-datetime-anthony-moore/), including a discussion of the sorts of problems that Microsoft was attempting to solve.  It's a bit old, but still it provides some insight.

Most of the article is dedicated to dealing with time zone issues and backward compatibility issues.  It appears that throughout the history of .NET versions, Microsoft realized that the problem space is very complex and everything they did seems to be a result of a desire for compromise between feature richness and simplicity.  Here is an interesting bit which seems to speak to (very briefly) the problem of a date-only representation:

> First, consider the landscape of date and time related scenarios:
>
> A. Legacy DateTime Interop (databases, COM, Win32, etc).
>
> B. Abstract DateTime scenarios (e.g. store starting time).
>
> C. Date-only scenarios.
>
> D. Time-only scenarios.
>
> E. Absolute time scenarios. (e.g. file time).
>
> F. Server scenarios with dates from multiple time zones where the original local time must be retained.
>
> **Scenarios C-D might be even better handled by dedicated Date and Time types. These options are still on the table, although they will not be in the .NET 3.5 release.**

So it seems they *did* consider a Date data type and it was still on the table when this blog was written.  A bit more explanation can be found elsewhere in the article:

> There was a lot of desire to keep the type system simple, and while a time zone aware DateTime was better at representing absolute points in time such as a file time-stamp, it got awkward when doing certain things....Representing whole dates, e.g. the type for a calendar control to return.  **Obviously a “Date” type is an even better way of representing this, and many people have asked for separate Date and Time types, but in V1.0 there was a desire to keep the number of base types small to limit complexity of the platform.** This feature request is definitely still on the table, although not planned for .NET 3.5

So I think the answer is... yes, they did think about it... no, they haven't done it yet, because it raises certain problems and there is a desire to keep the overall platform simple.

Meanwhile, they have released the newer [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) structure, which addresses some of the time zone issues.  But not any date-only issue.  Hopefully the date-only issues will be next up for consideration.

Answer (score -1):

Yes C# properties can be attributed to just emit the date:

```
[XmlElement("EndDt", DataType = "date", IsNullable = true)]
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }


public bool ShouldSerializeEndDate()
{
    return EndDate.HasValue;
}
```

To avoid time zone issues use UTC dates.

If you want just the date in code use `EndDate.Date`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.